# QWidget in delegate: no repaint upon mouseover, therefore MouseOver state cannot be checked

Tags: c++, qt

It does work on Linux+KDE, but not on Windows/OSX/Linux + XFCE.

I have a list view, the items are custom widgets, and the delegate for the list view's items does not get paint() calls if mouse is over the elements.

Tried to simulate the event via css ( :hover ), but it seems it is not working for QWidgets.

Am I missing something, or it's really a feature missing on platforms other than KDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to turn on mouse tracking.

[QWidget::setMouseTracking(bool)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop)

Comment: Doing this on the parent listview worked, thanks. I tried it first on the widget itself, but this one is more logical.
Strange that there are such differences between default values under KDE and non-KDE